# why fingerprintsimilarty in my code does not work?

Tags: java, android, audio, fingerprinting, musicg

I'm creating an application to recognize the sound of two wave files, for doing this I have found that "Musicg" library is used for that purpose. so I just write a simple code into my project to see if the sound are similar or not, but when I run the project it crashes, then I found that when the program comes to fingerprintSimilarity = wave.getFingerprintSimilarity(wave1); then it crashes, so can anyone tell me where did I do any mistakes?

here is my simple code

```
FingerprintSimilarity fingerprintSimilarity;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Wave wave = new Wave("sampledata/cock_a_1.wav");
        Wave wave1 = new Wave("sampledata/cock_a_1.wav");
        
        fingerprintSimilarity = wave.getFingerprintSimilarity(wave1);


       float score = fingerprintSimilarity.getScore();
       float similarity = fingerprintSimilarity.getSimilarity();
       Log.d("hi","score :" +score+ "\n Similarity :" + similarity);


    }
```

it gives me these errors:

03-24 23:42:41.984 2817-2817/com.example.fingerprint E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.fingerprint, PID: 2817
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fingerprint/com.example.fingerprint.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.musicg.wave.WaveHeader.getSampleRate()' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.musicg.wave.WaveHeader.getSampleRate()' on a null object reference
at com.musicg.fingerprint.FingerprintManager.extractFingerprint(FingerprintManager.java:69)
at com.musicg.wave.Wave.getFingerprint(Wave.java:329)
at com.musicg.wave.Wave.getFingerprintSimilarity(Wave.java:335)
at com.example.fingerprint.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: Please provide a stack trace

Comment: Today, I checked the code again, I found these errors :(

Comment: The error seems pretty clear: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.musicg.wave.WaveHeader.getSampleRate()' on a null object reference at com.musicg.fingerprint.FingerprintManager.extractFingerprint(FingerprintManager.java:69)`. You either haven't initialized your `WaveHeader`, or you've set it to `null`.

Comment: Actually, This is all the code I have. I haven't use WaveHeader class!!!

Answer (score 0):

The Wave() method accepts the "Inputstream" as a parameter and not the file's path.
Convert the file's path to an Inpustream type then put it into the wave parameter.